# Pygtk gtk.Entry() and multiple get_text() answers

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm using pygtk to make a questionnaire type application and in particular I'm struggling with one aspect.

I've tried to design it so that you can ask one or two people at a time. So I have radio buttons that the user can select between either person one or person two. The reason I've done it this way is so that I only need to use one set of `gtk.Entry()` widgets, `gtk.ComboBox()` widgets,...etc.

So what I currently have set up is an "assign data" method where, depending on which person you've asked, it saves the `get_text()` information to a specific variable.

I was wondering if there was some cleverer way of having the specific person's information for the fields they've already entered appear in the widgets when you select them with the radio buttons other than just a long list of `widget.set_text() = specific_variable`?

Thanks

Comment: I think that even _clever functions_ use `widget.set_text()` inside its code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you named your widgets (e.g, in a GtkBuilder file or manually), you can do the following:

```
widgets = [w for w in container_widget.get_children() if hasattr(w, "get_text")]
value_dict = {}

# save values to dictionary
for widget in widgets:
    value_dict[widget.get_name()] = widget.get_text()

# load values from dict
for widget in widgets:
    widget.set_text(value_dict[widget.get_name()])
```

If the widgets don't have names, you can just use `enumerate`, but that is a little more fragile.